# Oracle previous month's 15 date?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get previous month's 15 date in a format YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Can you add additional clarification such as expected inputs and outpots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')` to get the start of the current month and then add `-1` months to get the previous month and then add 14 days (to go from the 1st to the 15th of the month) and then use `TO_CHAR` to apply the format you require:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1) + INTERVAL '14' DAY,
         'YYYYMMDD'
       ) AS dt
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | DT |
> | --- |
> | 20220615 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccaffb15e11974e6e2f8ec3355346e6d)*